# For torsion $\Lambda $ modules, pseudo isomorphism is symmetric.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to see that for finitely generated torsion $\Lambda (= \mathbb Z_p [[ T ]]) $ modules, pseudo isomorphism is symmetric I.e. $M\sim N$ implies $N\sim M$.
I have a proof, but I do not understand all the details. It first says to pick an irreducible $f$ which is outside support of $M$ and $N$ by which I understand that $(f) \not \supset Ann(M)$ and $(f) \not \supset Ann(N)$.

> But why does such irreducible $f$ exist?

Now this gives us an isomorphism $M\otimes _\Lambda \Lambda [1/f] \simeq N\otimes _\Lambda \Lambda [1/f]$

> How did we get this isomorphism?

My guess is we tensored the exact sequence we get from pseudo isomorphism $M\sim N$. But how do finite modules become $0$ when tensored with $\Lambda [1/f]$?
Once this is established we get a map $\phi : N \otimes \Lambda [1/f] \xrightarrow \sim M \otimes \Lambda [1/f]$. From this we recover a map $N \rightarrow M$ by multiplying $\phi$ by a suitable power of $f$ since $N$ is finitely generated.

> Why is the cokernel finite?

Comment: Given the exact sequence $$
0 \to F_1 \to M \to N \to F_2 \to 0
$$ where $F_1,F_2$ are finite and thus torsion  $\Lambda$-modules, the $f$ you take could be (although I don't know whether this is what the author of your proof intended) the product of finitely many generators of the ideal $\text{Ann}(F_1)$ with finitely many generators of the ideal $\text{Ann}(F_2)$. Then your second isomorphism follows by what you mentioned.

Are you sure it's required that $f$ is irreducible?

Hope this helps:)